# BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to execute my spring boot application by running the jar created with maven and getting below exception which is not getting resolved after so many attempts. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

I am very new to springboot and I am in starting phase of learning

Thanks in advance.

Please find below exception trace.

```
16:48:24.654 [restartedMain] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@b0bc179: startup date [Sat Sep 30 16:48:24 IST 2023]; root of context hierarchy
16:48:25.400 [restartedMain] WARN  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.airkomm.SpringMvcApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
16:48:25.415 [restartedMain] ERROR o.s.b.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.airkomm.SpringMvcApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:233)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.airkomm.SpringMvcApplication.main(SpringMvcApplication.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:170)
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:158)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 26 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Below is my POM.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.airkomm.web.portal</groupId>
    <artifactId>airkomm-web-portal</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>AirkommWeb</name>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!---    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!---    -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>1.9.13</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.4.1</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.4.1</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.4.1</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>




        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>airkommWebPortal</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
# ====================================+
#==========================
# = Data Source
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://10.3.60.28:3306/airkommweb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&connectTimeout=300
#spring.datasource.username = vidbox
#spring.datasource.password = vidbox
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/airkommweb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&connectTimeout=300
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
#spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://10.3.60.76:3306/airkommweb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&connectTimeout=300
#spring.datasource.username = airkomm4
#spring.datasource.password = My@sql9776


# Here 'test2' is the database name
spring.seconddatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/dnddb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&connectTimeout=300
spring.seconddatasource.username=root
spring.seconddatasource.password=root
#spring.seconddatasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.3.60.28:3306/dnddb?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&failOverReadOnly=false&maxReconnects=10&connectTimeout=300
#spring.seconddatasource.username=vidbox
#spring.seconddatasource.password=vidbox
spring.seconddatasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

# ==============================================================
# = Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# ==============================================================
# = Show or not log for each sql query
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# ==============================================================
# = Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update, validate, none)
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

# ==============================================================
# = The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
# ==============================================================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# ==============================================================
# = Spring Security / Queries for AuthenticationManagerBuilder
# ==============================================================
spring.queries.users-query=SELECT username,password,status FROM user WHERE status=1 and userInteractionMode in (0,1) and username=?
spring.queries.roles-query=select u.username, r.roleName from user u inner join user_role ur on(u.userId=ur.userId) inner join role r on(ur.roleId=r.roleId) where u.username=?

# ==============================================================
# = Initialize the database using data.sql script
# ==============================================================
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=never
mmsfileupload.path=C:/application/Apache Software Foundation/apache/htdocs
mmsfileupload.format=zip
msisdnfileupload.path=C:/application/Apache Software Foundation/apache/htdocs
msisdnfileupload.format=csv
smsfileupload.path=C:/application/Apache Software Foundation/apache/htdocs
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
# ==============================================================
# = Logging related configurations
# ==============================================================
logging.level.root=info
logging.level.com.airkomm=debug
#spring.profiles.active=dev
logging.console=STDOUT
logging.pattern.console=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger.%M - %msg%n
logging.path=C:/logs/airkommWebPortal
#logging.path=/opt/tomcat/logs/app/logs
logging.file=${logging.path}/log.log
logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
```

My requirement is just to run this project!  I have tried running it many times but it is not working.

The SpringMvcApplication.java is annotated correctly it seems.

```
package com.airkomm;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMvcApplication  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringMvcApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(SpringMvcApplication.class);
    }
    
}
```

I already have done maven clean & install that was not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you comment out the scope in spring-boot-starter-tomcat

```
 <scope>provided</scope>
```

Comment: :- Thanks sir for the help, its worked I only reloaded the pom.xml after changing!